# БОТЫ — сибирская обувь!

Tags: этимология

Каким образом сибирская обувь - **БОТЫ** (упаки и бахилы, т.е. сапог чулком, высокие башмаки) могли иметь корень-основу в греческом (**ΜΠ**ΟΤΑ, чит. **Б**ОТА - "**БОТЫ**")?

Неужели сибиряки, оренбуржцы или тамбовцы общались с кем-то из европейцев, чтобы назвать свою национальную обувь на европейский манер, т.е. БОТАМИ?

Жили сотни лет без названия, пока португальцы с испанцами не подсказали им **как именно** называется обувь, которую они носят!
Странно.

Кстати **БОТАЛЫ** или **БУТАЛЫ** — это сибирское и оренбургское выражение, означающее сапожищи, большие просторные сапоги (В. Даль).

А вот **БОТАТЬ** — тамбовское выражение, означающее — качать ногами, стучать ногами в широких сапогах (В.Даль).

Поэтому нисколько не верится, что нем. **ВОТTЕ**, исп. **ВОТА**, порт. **ВОТА**, тур. **ВОТ** или греч. **БОТА** могли появиться раньше русского **БОТЫ** (**БОТАЛЫ**).

Comment: *Неужели сибиряки, оренбуржцы или тамбовцы общались с кем-то из европейцев, чтобы назвать свою национальную обувь на европейский манер, т.е. БОТАМИ?- нет,конечно. "Боты" в переводе с беларуского "сапоги".* — За сотни лет оккупации в Сибирь было выслано насильно или бежали от войн (например во время Первой мировой),несколько миллионов беларусов (литвинов). Поэтому в Сибири,в регионе населённом тюрскими народами и появились европейцы, которых потом стали называть "русскими", но которые сохранили свой "говор" в том числе и отдельные беларуские слова.

Answer (score 2):

боты
﻿

бо́ты

мн. "сапожки, род обуви", засвидетельствовано с XV в. в Радзивиловской рукописи Пов. Врем. Лет. (Срезн. I, 158). Вероятно, через др.-польск. bot (XV – XVI вв.), but (bót); см. Брюкнер, KZ 48, 175 и сл.; не непосредственно из франц. botte; ср. Гамильшег, EW 123 и сл., вопреки Mi. EW 20; Бернекеру 1, 77; Преобр. 1, 39.

Comment: А если БОТЫ были в сгоревшей или уничтоженной Романовыми русской летописи 9 или 10 века?

Выходит - нет летописи, нет и древнего слова?

Или, хотите, сказать, в 15 веке каким-то образом русские люди подслушали у испанцев как им называть свои сапоги, которые они шили сотни лет до того?

Comment: Обод

обод род. п. -а; обо́да "круговой широкий ремень конской шлеи по бокам лошади" (Даль), укр. о́бiд "обод колеса", блр. во́бод, др.-русск., цслав. ободъ, сербохорв. о̏бо̑д "край", словен. оbо̑d "кольцевой обод на сите", польск. obód, -оdu "обод". Праслав. *оbvоdъ. От об- и веду́. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973


сопоставлять надо.

Comment: Обод = БОТЫ ?

Такая этимология?

На каком основании?